# When marbling cake, can density of chocolate cake impact the rising of the vanilla cake?

Tags: baking, cake, leavening

I have specific bakers who I really love their recipes for different kinds of cake - for example Stella Parks. Because she doesn't have a recipe for a marble cake, I'm trying to decide whether I'll be successful when trying to marble two of my favorites of her cakes.

Some of the concerns I have relate to density of batter - for example, a chocolate cake that's more fudgy/dense might prevent a lighter vanilla cake from rising properly. The two recipes I'm looking at are found on the Serious Eats website - [Chocolate](https://www.seriouseats.com/bravetarts-devils-food-cake), [vanilla](https://www.seriouseats.com/classic-vanilla-butter-cake-recipe). I've created a table below with the amounts of primary ingredients for comparison purposes, as a note, both recipes are supposed to be for a three-layer cake:

| Ingredient | Chocolate | Vanilla |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Flour | 9 oz all purpose 3 oz cocoa powder | 16 oz all purpose |
| Sugar | 16 oz light brown | 16 oz granulated |
| Butter | 12 oz | 8 oz |
| Liquid | 12 oz coffee 6 oz chocolate, melted | 16 oz whole milk |
| Eggs | 6 large, cold 3 yolks, cold | 3 large, room temp |
| Leavening | 1 tbsp baking soda | 4 1/2 tsp baking powder |

With all of the extra eggs, the density looks concerning. Is it? Would I have more success if I find another chocolate cake recipe that's more similar to the vanilla cake?

While there's an [existing question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/can-i-marble-two-cakes-that-call-for-different-cooking-temperatures) that focuses on baking temperature and time, I'm curious whether there are other factors worth considering.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't mix those two cake recipes, personally.  The chocolate cake is *much* more dense than the vanilla, with almost twice as much liquid.  Further, in the recipe, the vanilla batter is fluffed up, whereas the chocolate cake isn't (and can't be).  I would assume that, if you mixed those two, what would come out of the oven would actually be two layers, with the chocolate on the bottom.

When I worked in a bakery, how we did the marble cake was that the chocolate portion was exactly the same recipe as the vanilla, with 10% of the flour swapped out for cocoa powder.

Comment: And (to me) that's the big downside of marble cakes - the chocolate parts look so tempting, but they're actually a disappointment, just being a slightly chocolate-flavoured n sponge cake  (note UK usage of sponge as in Victoria sponge, which includes butter).

Comment: Not gonna argue with you.  I made lots of marble cake in my time, but I didn't eat it.